# SQL | Shuffle order set by row_number based on another table

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, redshift

I need to manually shuffle the order set by row_number in a table based order mentioned in the different table -

Table A

| Name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

Table B

| name | manual_order_no |
| --- | --- |
| C | 1 |
| D | 3 |

Expected result using table B

| name | final_order_no |
| --- | --- |
| C | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| D | 3 |
| B | 4 |

I am trying with below query but it doesn't fully work ; banging my head to see what am I missing :O

```
with t1 as (select name,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name asc) as default_order_no
            from A),
     t2 as (
         select t1.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY coalesce(B.manual_order_no, default_order_no)) as order_no
         from B
                  right join t1 on B.name = t1.name)
select t2.name, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY order_no asc) as final_order_no
from t2
```

Comment: Please don't spam the tags. Which DBMS are you really using?

Comment: What is the rule that assigns the final order 2 to A and 4 to B?

Comment: *I need to manually shuffle the order set* I do not see the shuffling, I see non-numerated rows enumeration with existing numbers skipping/storing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
nums AS ( SELECT 1 manual_order_no
          UNION ALL
          SELECT manual_order_no + 1 
          FROM nums 
          WHERE manual_order_no < ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                    FROM A )
),
A1 AS ( 
    SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B USING (name)
    WHERE B.manual_order_no IS NULL
), 
nums1 AS (
    SELECT manual_order_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM nums
    LEFT JOIN B USING (manual_order_no)
    WHERE B.manual_order_no IS NULL
)
SELECT name, manual_order_no
FROM B
UNION ALL
SELECT A1.name, nums1.manual_order_no
FROM A1
JOIN nums1 USING (rn)
ORDER BY manual_order_no
```

and

```sql
INSERT INTO B (name, manual_order_no)
WITH RECURSIVE
nums AS ( SELECT 1 manual_order_no
          UNION ALL
          SELECT manual_order_no + 1 
          FROM nums 
          WHERE manual_order_no < ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                    FROM A )
),
A1 AS ( 
    SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B USING (name)
    WHERE B.manual_order_no IS NULL
), 
nums1 AS (
    SELECT manual_order_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM nums
    LEFT JOIN B USING (manual_order_no)
    WHERE B.manual_order_no IS NULL
)
SELECT A1.name, nums1.manual_order_no
FROM A1
JOIN nums1 USING (rn)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a767751d4f21961ba3946a457f5baa40